# TypeError: null is not an object error when importing 'react-native-fs'

Tags: react-native, react-native-fs

The line that causes the error is this:

```
const RNFS = require('react-native-fs')
```

The error I get is:

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'RNFSManager.RNFSFileTypeRegular')
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem with your autolinking. Do

1. `cd android && ./gradlew clean`
2. Then in your root folder `npx react-native run-android`

   **Note** : Make sure to uninstall the application from your emulator or real device before step 2.

Comment: I'm using Expo, so I don't have the android and ios folders.

Comment: You can use `expo r -c` to clean cache and then step 2.

Comment: Apparently you need to clear the cache, I do not the command for same for expo. I faced the same issue and cleaning gradle and then step 2 command running again worked for me.